# directory name contains special characters

Tags: java, directory

I have to use a exe for running a certain function. But the directory contains certain folders with special characters like ".","-" so its not getting executed. Can I rename the directory name as we do for file names, I'm not sure what needs to be done.

Im using Linux environment.
Here is the piece of code,

```
               newFilename = /sites/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/dev/deploy/meen.war/temp/filename

               String[] command_ary = { directory+"lib/fcrc", newFilename };

               process = runtime.exec( command_ary);
               int exit_val = process.waitFor();
```

fcrc is my exe, and its followed by the file name, here the directory contains special characters so its creating the problem. whereas from other directory Im able to execute,But I need to access from this directory only

and exit_val  returns 1

Can anyone suggest me?
Thank-You

Comment: Are you having problems referring to the folders from the command line or from code? If from the command line, this is not the correct forum (try http://superuser.com/). If from code, show us your code. Also, let us know what environment you are using (OS, shell version if applicable, etc.).

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: It's currently very difficult to understand (1) *why* special characters are a problem, (2) what you're trying to do, (3) how you're trying to do it, (4) what you've tried, (5) what this has to do with Java (given the Java tag). Please try to clarify.

Comment: (1) why special characters are a problem-because the exe doesn't allow special characters, its written that way so i cant do anything  (2) what you're trying to do-Im trying to find the value by running the exe (3) how you're trying to do it- i have to pass the complete filename along with the directory name to the exe (4) what you've tried-i have googled to find a way (5) what this has to do with Java-since the code is written in Java so i have tagged java

Comment: Is fcrc a compiled executable (as you seem to suggest), or is it a shell script which calls on Java to run a jar file, or something else?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want to rename `jboss-5.1.0.GA` to `jboss510GA` and `meen.war` to `meenwar` on your file system so you're final filename is `/sites/jboss510GA/server/dev/deploy/meenwar/temp/filename` (and do so in a generic way)? I'll also just note that freely renaming directories to get a program to work because of restrictions in that program seems like the wrong course of action and, apart from not always working because of directory locking issues, may cause rather significant issue elsewhere.

Comment: Is "special characters" everything that's not `[A-Za-z0-9]`?

Comment: yes, renaming it to something which will remove all the special characters not in [A-Za-z0-9]

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say it is really hard to understand the problem without seeing your code. If the problem is that your `fcrc` executable can't deal with the path name, then I propose that you either copy or move the file temporarily; alternatively that you create a link to the file and pass the link to your executable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping those characters an escape sign?

For example on Windows if you want to access a folder with a space in the name you should escape it:

```
C:\Program/ Files\something\file.txt
```

This would reach file.txt inside of "something" folder in "Program Files".

If your situation is like this or you use folders with "." signs try to escape the special chars in the path in a similar way.